# How to push/force state update in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I know there is already a lot of questions related to state updates. But I'm not able to get my head around why it is not working. or is there any simple way to force update state ?

I have a click handler that does this

**Below code works perfectly fine**

```
onButtonClick(){
   var state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)) // To mutate the state;
   state.name = "newName";
   this.setState(state)
}
```

**Below doesn't update the state.items with "Hellow"**

```
onButtonClick(){
   var state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)) // To mutate the state;
   state.items.push("Fourth")
   this.setState(state)
}
```

I have used similar example in a project I'm building but not able to figure out why above syntax isn't working.

1. Open https://imvetri.github.io/ui-editor/
2. Click "Editor" on left
3. Open debugger
4. Move mouse on black area and right click.
5. Set breakpoint at line #46. Its the render function, if you inspect this.state you will notice that the `this.state.items` wouldn't have changed

**Expected:**

First

Second

Third

Fourth

**Actual:**

First

Second

Third

Comment: Unrelated, but stringifying/parsing state likely isn't the most efficient way to do this. It's also not clear how the code you link to is related to your example snippets. There's no array operation around the `debugger` statement. There's no particular reason this shouldn't work (assuming the click handler is properly bound) that I see off the top of my head.

Comment: Now it doesn't work at all; there's no right-click handler. The snippets you provide are insufficient to diagnose the problem, and appear to not be related in any way to your actual code. I don't know where `onShowContextMenu` is defined, but it sets state directly. I don't know of any way to help you.

Comment: I'd also caution against assuming everything can be de-/serialized in the way you expect.

Comment: Sorry, Since you mentioned that the example here and there didn't make sense so I was making changes in the mean time. Now it should be working

Comment: The code in the function with the `debugger`, `editoronContextMenu`, does not attempt to add anything to an array, it sets the `style.top` and `style.left` of whatever the first element in `state.ContextMenuOptions` is.

Comment: @Vetrivel 1. dont mutate state. 2. the first works because you're passing a new string into `setState` whereas the second you're passing the same array so react doesn't re-render thinking nothing changed. you will need to pass in a new array.

Comment: @Vetrivel There's no way to help with this without complete, meaningful details. Questions need to stand on their own: the code in the question will work as you'd expect, which means additional context is required. https://imgur.com/a/ivIwESX

Comment: Okay. Let me come back with a simple snippet

Comment: @Da Sorry my bad. Its not working with my project but working perfectly fine as a separate react file. Here is the snippet I tried to rule out https://codepen.io/iminui/pen/dyGMpOJ

Comment: @Vetrivel This could mean any of several things, including 1) not everything in state is de-/serializable, 2) you're not working with the state you think you are, 3) sthng else. I'd look at the first two first.

Answer (score 0):

Mutate the state to trigger the update, something like this:

```
onButtonClick(){
   var items = this.state.items;
   this.setState({items: [...items, "Helow"])
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be a better way to update the state, but in the snippets provided, the state *is* being mutated appropriately (if inefficiently). (Assuming everything in the state is serializable.)